# Play Framework: How to sort JSON alphabetically

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Given the following JSON...

```
{
   "z": 100,
   "b": 50,
   "q": 12
}
```

How do I sort the keys alphabetically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple enough, but (obviously) we need to make sure we have a `JsObject`.

```
val js = Json.parse("""{
   "z": 100,
   "b": 50,
   "q": 12
}""")

val jsObject = js.as[JsObject] // Not actually safe, but bear with me
```

The fields are simply stored in a field called `fields` as a `Seq[(String, JsValue)]`.

```
scala> jsObject.fields
res5: Seq[(String, play.api.libs.json.JsValue)] = ListBuffer((z,100), (b,50), (q,12))
```

We can make a new `JsObject` with the same fields, except sorted.

```
scala> JsObject(jsObject.fields.sortBy(_._1))
res6: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"b":50,"q":12,"z":100}
```

Earlier, I mentioned using `as[JsObject]` is unsafe, because if our `JsValue` is actually an array or string, it will throw an exception. The safer way to handle a `JsValue` here would be to pattern match on `JsObject` and sort it, and do nothing to any other type. It is simple enough to create a method that recursively sorts all keys:

```
def sortJs(js: JsValue): JsValue = js match {
    case JsObject(fields) => JsObject(fields.sortBy(_._1).map { case (k, v) => (k, sortJs(v)) })
    case _ => js
}

val js = Json.parse("""{
   "z": 100,
   "b": {"k": 1, "j": 3, "i": 98},
   "q": 12
}""")

scala> sortJs(js)
res8: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"b":{"i":98,"j":3,"k":1},"q":12,"z":100}
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue that Yuchen had with the accepted answer.  This is how I was able to get it to work:

```
def sortJs(js: JsValue): JsValue = js match {
  case JsObject(fields) => JsObject(fields.toSeq.sortBy(_._1).map { case (key, value) => (key, sortJs(value.asInstanceOf[JsValue]))})
  case _ => js
}
```

The above version doesn't handle recursively sorting JsArray.  This version handles that.

```
def sortJs(js: JsValue): JsValue = js match {
  case JsObject(fields) => JsObject(fields.toSeq.sortBy(_._1).map { case (key, value) => (key, sortJs(value.asInstanceOf[JsValue])) })
  case JsArray(array) => JsArray(array.map(e => sortJs(e)))
  case other => other
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me (tested with):

- Scala version: 2.11.8
- Play json version: 2.6.10

```
scala> val js = Json.parse("""{
     |    "z": 100,
     |    "b": 50,
     |    "q": 12
     | }""")
js: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"z":100,"b":50,"q":12}

scala> def sortJs(js: JsValue): JsValue = js match {
     | case o: JsObject =>
     |   JsObject(o.fields.sortBy(_._1).map { case (k, v) => (k, sortJs(v)) })
     | case _ => js
     | }
sortJs: (js: play.api.libs.json.JsValue)play.api.libs.json.JsValue

scala> sortJs(js)
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"b":50,"q":12,"z":100}
```

---

Just FTR: this was the error that I had with the accepted answer:

```
scala> def sortJs(js: JsValue): JsValue = js match {
     |     case JsObject(fields) => JsObject(fields.sortBy(_._1).map { case (k, v) => (k, sortJs(v)) })
     |     case _ => js
     | }
<console>:16: error: value sortBy is not a member of scala.collection.Map[String,play.api.libs.json.JsValue]
           case JsObject(fields) => JsObject(fields.sortBy(_._1).map { case (k, v) => (k, sortJs(v)) })
                                                    ^
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: play.api.libs.json.JsValue
           case JsObject(fields) => JsObject(fields.sortBy(_._1).map { case (k, v) => (k, sortJs(v)) })
                                                                                                 ^
```